# Discrepancy Between Created File Size and Displayed File Size in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.

I created a demo file of size 10MB using the following command:

```
yes 'This is a test file.' | head -c 10MB > testfile.txt
```

This command essentially creates a 10MB file named "testfile.txt", filled with the repeating string 'This is a test file.'.

Now, I ran the following command to find the created file's size:

```
du -sh testfile.txt
```

And I got the following output:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. **What does the "M" in 9.6M stand for: Megabytes (MB) or Mebibyte (MiB)**?
2. **Why does the system display 9.6M (I am not sure whether its 9.6MB or 9.6MiB) when I created a file of size 10MB**?

I have gone through similar questions on stackoverflow, but not able to figure out why this discrepancy occurs. I will appreciate a detailed answer.

Comment: `10*1000*1000/1024/1024 = 9.5367431`. Looks like 9.6 is rounded up. What does `wc -c testfile.txt` output? 10 million? Then `10MB` is megabytes.

Comment: @knittl `wc -c testfile.txt` is showing 10000000

Answer (score 0):

From [this `head` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html):

> NUM may have a multiplier suffix: ... MB 1000 * 1000, M 1024 * 1024, ...

So the 10MB you write to the file is ten million bytes, which is about 9.6 MiB.

To write 10 MiB use just `M` and not `MB`.

Comment: Why does the system show file size in MiB, not MB (with the `du` command)? Is it the default?

Comment: @HKS [The `du` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) uses the same suffixes. `M` for MiB and `MB` for MB.